# How to add text to a menu item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-actionbar

I am building an android application. I want to add contents to each menu items. I tried but could not add. Please anybody help.

**res/menu/main.xml**

```
   <menu xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
        xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"; 
        xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
        tools:context="com.example.newmenu.MainActivity" >
        <item 
           android:id="@+id/about"
           android:title="@string/About">
       </item>
       <item android:id="@+id/help"
       android:title="@string/Help">
       </item>
        </menu>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Below is the code of res/menu/main.xml 

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.newmenu.MainActivity" >
    
    
    <item android:id="@+id/about" 
        android:title="@string/About"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/help" 
        android:title="@string/Help"></item>

       
</menu>

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Thanks Blacklight.  Now i want to remove the app name from the header and only retain the logo.  Hoe to do this?

Comment: @user3165429 this post may help you http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inflate this in your `Activity` or `Fragment` in [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)()

More information at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now i want to add some contents to each menu items. How can I do this?

Comment: @user3165429 you should accept this answer and then create a new question as that is now a separate issue. Glad to have helped.

Comment: Now I am unable to Ask New Question, Why is that happening. An error message is being displayed as shown below:                                    Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.